# Unknown error during face_recognition module in python

Tags: python, face-recognition

[i am not able to install face_recognition module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhqSw.png)

whenever I try to install the face recognition module I get this unknown error,
I have already updated the Cmake and pip to the latest version but still, this error shows.
It's like:

subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\Users\Ashish\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9szfcst7\dlib\tools\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Ashish\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9szfcst7\dlib\build\lib.win32-3.7', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\users\ashish\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\Ashish\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9szfcst7\dlib\build\lib.win32-3.7']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

```
----------------------------------------
```

Command "c:\users\ashish\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\Ashish\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9szfcst7\dlib\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Ashish\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-psz1uqhy\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Ashish\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9szfcst7\dlib\

Comment: i have uploaded the screenshot of that error please check if you can help me.

Comment: In the future, you might want to cut and paste the error into the question instead of using a screenshot.

Comment: now look at this..

Comment: It is better, now to improve further, consider indenting the code you copied so that it is recognized as "code". To do so: (1) edit your post, (2) select the line of code, including the error. (3) Then use CTRL+K to indent it automatically.

Answer (score 2):

### workaround

Assuming you are using Anaconda3 (based on the screenshot) and since the dependency of `face_recognition` that need to be compiled is named `dlib` and is available on [conda-forge](https://conda-forge.org/feedstocks/), I suggest you try the following:

(1) Open Annaconda terminal

(2) Add conda forge channel

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
```

(3) Create and activate a new environment

```
conda create -n my_experiments
conda activate my_experiments
```

(4) install dlib

```
conda install dlib
```

(5) install other dependencies of `face_recognition` that are available on conda

```
conda install click numpy pillow
```

(6) install the models. Since they are not available on conda, the following should do it:

```
pip install face_recognition_models
```

(7) Last, since `face_recognition` is only composed of python script but not available on conda, you can then try this:

```
pip install face_recognition --no-deps
```

### the proper fix

Python wheels for both `dlib` and `face_recognition` should be made available.

A python wheel is package that contain python and also pre-compiled library code. This allows the user to easily install the package.

The latest release of dlib doesn't have any wheels available: https://pypi.org/project/dlib/19.15.0/#files

I will follow up and report an issue to the maintainer of dlib.